# Kotlin version is not update in gradle.build file

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, compiler-errors

I tried many times to update kotlin version but it shows me the old version instead of the latest one. This is a flutter project that tries to run the project. Here is a screenshot.

Please check and let me know what's wrong with it.

Thank you.

[Error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1pHc.png)

i need this solution.

Comment: Please share the error message instead of image

Comment: this is error that i got every time 

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':fluttertoast' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10'
    }
}
//$kotlin_version removed it to 1.5.31
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

Comment: this solution is not working.

Comment: did you opening android folder in android studio and run gradile also run flutter clean@MuhammadBilal